# Login page form

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin android and i have one question. Since there is one activity_main.axml i decided to make login form out of it. Now when login will be fine i want user to be redirected to 'real main page of program'. I think that's correct approach. Nevertheless i am not sure how should i redirect to next page and what type of item should i create in my project for "real main form" (this after login. And also should i hide activity_main.axml once redirected to real main form? Please of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using two different activities. First one will be for login, for example `Login.class`, and second will be user environment after login, let's name it `Main.class`

The transfer between two activities will be similar to this:

In `Login.class`

```
if(passwordIsCorrect){
  startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Main.class); //-> switch to Main activity
  finish(); //-> destroy Login activity
}
```

Comment: hi. bit confused with extension .class ? Thougt axml.

Comment: Well xml is just used in setContentView() in onCreate method of Activity or when inflating. Class is file with your Activity. I see now you are asking about axml. Do not have an experience with it, but should work similar as it is in android

Comment: as far as i undersoot if i startactivity and do nto finis() first one will be working behind because i am able to click back phone button go back to it. So the question is how to make programable button to go back? (same as go back button on phone). Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to navigate back, when a button is clicked, use onBackPressed method like this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
      @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) { 
        onBackPressed();
      } 
    });
  }

  @Override 
  public void onBackPressed() { 
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm not work, when i click back button with your code it is going back to previous page BUT application is minimized and also seems page 1 is resetet because i puted some text there and it s not once this action.

Comment: When you use finish in first activity, then you must use new Intent in second activity